# SQLAlchemy: Query a JSON column (PostgreSQL) containing array and counting matches

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm a bit new to SQLAlchemy and using JSON columns in db.

**My db model**

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
    
class Traydetails(db.Model):
    
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    traynumber = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    safety_data = db.Column(JSON)
```

**My JSON structure**

```
[{"Formulation": "Form1", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form2", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form3", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form4", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form5", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form6", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form7", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form8", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form9", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}, {"Formulation": "Form10", "Hazard Rating": "Class B"}]
```

**tried query-1**

```
hazard = Traydetails.query.filter(Traydetails.safety_data['Hazard Rating'].astext == "Class B").count()
```

It returns nothing.

**tried query-2**

```
hazard = Traydetails.query.filter(Traydetails.safety_data[0]['Hazard Rating'].astext.cast(Unicode) == "Class B").count()
```

It returns only one ( since i'm comparing to one position )

But My goal is to count how many class B are there in the hazardrating (key).
Note there will be different types of classes like Class A , Class B , class N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the postgres function `json_array_elements` to form a subquery which you can filter to retrieve the count of `Class B` hazard ratings:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
subq = session.query(func.json_array_elements(Traydetails.safety_data).label('safety_data')).subquery()

count = session.query(subq).filter(subq.c.safety_data.op('->>')('Hazard Rating') == 'Class B').count()
print(count)
```

The `filter` is using the safety_data labeled column of the subquery: `subq.c.safety_data`. With `.op` we are using an custom operator `->>` which will convert json to text. See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for more information about the operator.